# Paypal Subscription setting date

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have a paypal merchants account and I am trying to set up a monthly subscription service.

I have been using the merchants tool to try and create a subscribe button. This is no problem however, I don't know anything of the technical side and codes.

What I would like to do is to set up a monthly subscription service charging $22 every month.

I want the $22 to come out of peoples account on the 1st of every month.

If they sign up during the 1st to the 10th I would like to charge them the $22 immediately and then on the 1st of every month after that.

If they sign up on the 11th till the end of the month first payment will be on the 1st of the next month.

Do you think this is possible with paypal?

Thanks for taking the time to read my post and I hope the information is clear.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you think this is possible with paypal?

Yes.